# How can I find the logo of a token in the Cardano Token Registry?

Tags: token, api

I know this is the API for accesing the Cardano Token Registry (`https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/`) but I don't know how to get and process the logo image of a token from there.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/{subject}/properties/logo`. See the [API doc](https://input-output-hk.github.io/offchain-metadata-tools/api/latest/).